# Image caching using Glide in android

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images in my app. When app launches Home fragment loads in MainActivity in Home fragment I am fetching images in view pager.When I switch between the fragments and come back to Home fragment it takes sometime to load images in view pager why don't it loads images quickly as I am using Caching property provided by Glide.

What I have been doing so far is

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment{ 

ViewPager bannerViewPager;
BannerAdapter adapter;
List<BannerModel> banners;
TabLayout tabLayout;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
StringRequest stringRequest;    

private static final String URI = "https://www.example.com";

 public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    bannerViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.bannerViewpager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(bannerViewPager, true);

    banners = new ArrayList<>();

    loadViewPager();

    return view;

 }    

 public void loadViewPager() {

      requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

      stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,URI, new Response.Listener<String>() {

      @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String loadImages = jsonObject.getString("Image");

                    BannerModel model = new BannerModel(loadImages);
                    banners.add(model);

                }

                adapter = new BannerAdapter(banners,getActivity());

                bannerViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            }catch(JSONException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }

    },new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            TastyToast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error:"+error.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
        }
    });

      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  }

}
```

**GlideSingleton.java**

```
public class GlideSingleton {

private static GlideSingleton  obj;
public RequestOptions options;

private GlideSingleton(){

    options = new RequestOptions();
    options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);
}

public static synchronized GlideSingleton getInstance(){

    if(obj == null){

        obj = new GlideSingleton();
    }
    return obj;
  }
}
```

**BannerAdapter.java**

```
public class BannerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;
private List<BannerModel> banners;

public BannerAdapter(List<BannerModel> banners,Context context){

    this.banners = banners;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return banners.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view == o;
  }

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert layoutInflater != null;
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bannerlayout, null);

    ImageView offerImage = view.findViewById(R.id.offerImage);

    BannerModel model = banners.get(position);

    Glide.with(context).load(model.getBannerImage()).apply(GlideSingleton.getInstance().options).into(offerImage);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
  } 

}
```

Someone please let me know how can I load the images quickly once they get downloaded by network in image view.
Any help will be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Where have you placed your Glide code? In onStart() or onResume() of your fragment? If so, that explains why it 'reloads' again.

Comment: I have added my code in java class extending PagerAdapter.

Comment: i think you shoud have to use singleton pattern for RequestOptions and Glid i will help you from your trouble

Comment: @Adnan please share some code how can i implement it.

Comment: @Digvijay i have posted answer please try it may bi its help for you

Comment: @Adnan ,thanks bro i am trying it in my code get back to u soon.

Comment: @Adnan, I tried ur code but till it is taking some time to load images when i am switching between fragments.

Comment: `Glide.with(TheActivity.this)
   .load("http://sampleurl.com/sample.gif")
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
   .into(theImageView);`     [Check it](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

Comment: @Adnan, let me update my question with full code so that u will be able to get complete overview.

Comment: @Adnan, I updated my post please go through the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

**Create new class**

```
class SingletonRequestOptions
{
    private static SingletonRequestOptions  obj;
    public RequestOptions options;
    private SingletonRequestOptions () {
        options = new RequestOptions();
        options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);
    }

    // Only one thread can execute this at a time
    public static synchronized SingletonRequestOptions  getInstance()
    {
        if (obj==null)
            obj = new SingletonRequestOptions ();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**Update your line with this**

```
Glide.with(context).load(model.getBannerImage()).apply(SingletonRequestOptions.getInstance().options).into(offerImage);
```